# Stuck with nested redux reducers using combinereducers

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've looked at a bunch of examples of working with nested reducers, but I'm having a very strange problem.

I have the following initial state:

```html
window.store = configureStore({
  slider: {
    mainImageIndex: 0,
    pageNum: 1,
    perPage: 4, // Per supplied requirements
  },
});
```

The following in my index.js reducer (excluding all the imports):

```html
export default combineReducers({
  searchPhotos,
  slider: combineReducers({
    mainImageIndex: setMainImage,
    pageNum: nextPage,
    perPage: setPerPage,
  }),
  form: reduxFormReducer, // mounted under "form"
});
```

And my setMainInage.js reducer:

```html
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        mainImageIndex: action.mainImageIndex,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Attached are before and after screen grabs of the redux devtools.  Notice that after calling the SET_MAIN_IMAGE, the hierarcy inside the slider node changes.  For some reason instead of just updating the mainImageIndex, it's nesting a new mainImageIndex key under the original.  Anyone know what could be causing that?[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you have to use redux-immutable for this issue. your nested object need to be immutable.

Comment: I was trying to follow this idea, but I must be missing something: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/738

Answer (score 0):

The thing you have to check is what does your `action` contain ?

It seems that it contains something like that

```
{
    type: 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE',
    mainImageIndex: {
        mainImageIndex: 2
    },
}
```

Your reducer will be like

**1. First step**

```
case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
    return {
        ...state,
        mainImageIndex: action.mainImageIndex, 
    };
```

**2. Second step**

```
case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
    return {
        mainImageIndex: 0,
        pageNum: 1,
        perPage: 4,
        mainImageIndex: action.mainImageIndex, 
    };
```

**3. Third step**

```
case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
    return {
        mainImageIndex: 0,
        pageNum: 1,
        perPage: 4,
        mainImageIndex: {
            mainImageIndex: 2
        }, 
    };
```

**4. Fourth step**

```
case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
    return {
        pageNum: 1,
        perPage: 4,
        mainImageIndex: {
            mainImageIndex: 2
        }, 
    };
```

**What you should do**

Change the `action` payload in order to send something like that

```
{
    type: 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE',
    mainImageIndex: 2
}
```

or better

```
{
    type: 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE',
    payload: {
        mainImageIndex: 2,
    }
}
```

then use in your **reducer**

```
case 'SET_MAIN_IMAGE':
    return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
    };
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but the action only has 2 things in it.  Just logged it out:
{type: "SET_MAIN_IMAGE", mainImageIndex: 2}

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve the problem by creating a new reducer for the slider, and put all actions inside that one reducer, instead of having one function per file.  Then I could just do:

```html
export default combineReducers({
  searchPhotos,
  slider,
  form: reduxFormReducer, // mounted under "form"
});
```

I think there must still be a way to do it with multiple files, but maybe it does make sense to put all the actions for one part of state in the same reducer.